# lodash not trimming end and start

Tags: javascript, lodash

I got an array containing strings.
I want to make sure there are no space fillings in end or start of string, in middle is ok.

So I've tried using lodash by doing this:

```
var answers = req.body.answer.split(/;,/); // req.body.answer = 'nio,9'
answers = _.map(answers, _.trimEnd);
answers = _.map(answers, _.trimStart);
```

The result is this:

```
[ 'nio       ,      9' ] // answer before trim
[ 'nio       ,      9' ] // answer after trim
```

The wanted result is:

```
[ 'nio', '9']
```

Comment: What's does the answer array looks like?

Comment: [ 'nio       ,      9' ] is the answer array before and after trim. Sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: what do you have in req.body.answer?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem in your code is your regular expression you are using, you are trying to split the string where there are `;,` and I'm guessing you just want to split by `,` since your result is an array with only one string inside:

[ 'nio       ,      9' ]

you should use this regular exp instead:

```
var answers = req.body.answer.split(/,/);
```

or without any regular exp just do:

```
var answers = req.body.answer.split(',');
```